# event.screenX and external Javascript

Tags: javascript, events, cursor

I'm currently trying to retrieve the coordinates of the cursor using

```
function getCursor(event) {
    event.screenX;
    event.screenY;
}
```

I know you can reference this event by using something similar to

`<div onmousemove="getCursor(event)"></div>`

However I am currently trying to use a purely external javascript file and am attaching events like so:

```
element.onmousemove = getCursor
//or
element.onmousemove = function() {getCursor(parameters)}
```

**How would I be able to reference the event that these functions are attached to?**

Thank you in advance for any help!

*note: I do not use jQuery or any other javascript library*

### Update

[MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event) nvm! figured it out. You actually don't have to pass the param at all. `element.onmousemove = getCursor` works great as long as you have `function getCursor(event) {}`. Sorry bout that >_<.

### Double Update!

Read Sime's comment/answer

Comment: `element.onmousemove = getCursor;` doesn't work in IE8 and below...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:

```
element.onmousemove = function(e) {
    e = e || window.event;    
    getCursor(e);
}
```

The event object is passed as the first argument into the event handler function automatically. The exception is Internet Explorer 8 and below - `e = e || window.event;` will make it work in those versions of IE too.

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/DteK8/